# ASCII Characters objective C encryption

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, encryption, ascii

I am making an encryption app for iPhone and iPad (without strong algorithms, mainly for education and a bit of fun). I have already made Ceasar and Vergerne Ciphers. The algorithms work fine when I use only the first 127 standard ascii characters. When I change the function to include 255 characters (extended ascii), it won't work (both of the algorithms don't work). 
I think that there may be some sort of formatting characters that iOS devices don't show.

My question is which invisible ascii characters that can't be copied may I leave out? I want to make my own 'ascii code' with only visible characters.

Comment: 1. Supply the error information. 2. Supply a test case. 3. Separate the "encryption" from the UI, create a method for the encryption that is called by the action. Basically separate different things into separate methods, that makes understanding and debugging the code much easier.

Comment: Props on there black "hacker" cat on the keyboard, is the cat"s name Eve? ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the code corrections, but I will fix that later. The code should work perfectly, but I am having character problems. my question is more about the ASCII table. The Hacker cats name is lucy ;)